# Heatmap in R grouped by a specific column of a dataframe

Tags: r, heatmap

I have a dataframe with ~100 columns and ~900 rows from which I want to generate a heatmap. I want to group rows by 1 column (Grouping Factor), **to have 3 groups (A,B,C)** (showing the mean of each group) and I also need to scale the data. I have an example table below.

| Grouping Factor | Var1 | Var2 | Var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1.2 | 1.3 | 1.4 |
| B | 1.3 | 0.6 | 1.5 |
| C | 0.8 | 1.1 | 1.6 |
| C | 1.5 | 0.4 | 1.2 |
| C | 0.6 | 0.9 | 1.3 |
| A | 1.0 | 1.5 | 1.6 |
| B | 0.7 | 0.6 | 1.7 |
| B | 1.1 | 0.2 | 1.9 |
| A | 1.5 | 1.5 | 0.1 |

I have not been able to group the data by the grouping factor

Answer (score 0):

A row-wise scaled `heatmap` grouped by the first column

First generate a matrix with row names in the right order

```
mat <- as.matrix(df[order(df$Grouping.Factor),-1])
rownames(mat) <- df[order(df$Grouping.Factor),1]
```

then plot without clustering

```
heatmap(mat[nrow(mat):1,], Rowv=NA, Colv=NA)
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Grouping.Factor = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "A", 
"B", "B", "A"), Var1 = c(1.2, 1.3, 0.8, 1.5, 0.6, 1, 0.7, 1.1, 
1.5), Var2 = c(1.3, 0.6, 1.1, 0.4, 0.9, 1.5, 0.6, 0.2, 1.5), 
    Var3 = c(1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.2, 1.3, 1.6, 1.7, 1.9, 0.1)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

[image: heatmap plot]